# Learning about Symbolic links

Tags: linux, symlink

I am new to Linux, and am trying to understand symbolic links better.

From what I understand, when you create a symbolic link to a file, and you remove the source file manually from the folder without the terminal, the destination still has the file, but you can't open it anymore. Now, if I understood correctly, this is because the source file that the shortcut originates from was deleted, but because it was done manually the shortcut is still in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not matter how the original file went away. Doesn't even matter if the "original" file never existed. You can make a symbolic link to any name you like. The only bad thing is to make it to itself, because it thrashes round 50 times before it gets dizzy.

```
Paul--) ls -l Foo
ls: cannot access 'Foo': No such file or directory
Paul--) ln -s NeverHeardOfIt Foo
Paul--) ls -l Foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 paul paul 14 Dec 10 17:50 Foo -> NeverHeardOfIt
Paul--) cat Foo
cat: Foo: No such file or directory
Paul--) ls -lL Foo
ls: cannot access 'Foo': No such file or directory

Paul--) ln -s Whirly Whirly
Paul--) ls -l Whirly
lrwxrwxrwx 1 paul paul 6 Dec 10 17:51 Whirly -> Whirly
Paul--) ls -lL Whirly
ls: cannot access 'Whirly': Too many levels of symbolic links
Paul--) cat Whirly
cat: Whirly: Too many levels of symbolic links
```